# Getting Text from Json Respond from Aeris API

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, sdk

I am trying to get "General" text to display on the html from the API under details.risk.type.

The JSON Response Is This...

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": "6404f97b644160f2ea374e2d",
            "details": {
                "product": "convective",
                "category": "cat",
                "day": 1,
                "range": {
                    "minTimestamp": 1678046400,
                    "maxTimestamp": 1678104000,
                    "minDateTimeISO": "2023-03-05T14:00:00-06:00",
                    "maxDateTimeISO": "2023-03-06T06:00:00-06:00"
                },
                "issuedTimestamp": 1678043820,
                "issuedDateTimeISO": "2023-03-05T13:17:00-06:00",
                "risk": {
                    "type": "general",
                    "name": "general thunderstorms risk",
                    "code": 1
                }
            },
            "geoPoly": null
        }
    ]
}
```

With the AERIS JS SDK / HTML Code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AerisWeather API</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

    <script defer src="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/sdk/js/latest/aerisweather.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        const aeris = new AerisWeather('[ID]', '[SECRET]');

        const request = aeris.api()
            .endpoint('convective/outlook')
            .place('chicago,il')
            .format('json')
            .filter('all');
        request.get().then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get "General" text to display on the html from the API under details.risk.type.

Answer (score 0):

#### Traverse down the tree of the object to get to the "general"

Thanks for providing the correct content of the JSON response in the comments below. The JSON response in the question itself is incorrect. Your comment shows that the object returned is the `details` object from the object at the top of your question.

Therefore you only need to go into the `risk` property, and you are done!

After `<body>` insert a DIV into which you can put your result.

```
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Replace:

```
 console.log(result);
```

with:

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
  console.log(result.risk.type);
  const outputDiv = document.getElementById("result"); 
  outputDiv.textContent += result.risk.type;
```

Comment: No luck, nothing displays on the html.

Comment: Can you clarify? console.log(result) displays the whole object above, and yet console.log(result.details.risk.type) displays _nothing_? Are you sure you are looking in the right place? Shift-control-i which will reveal the Console. If you want the result inside the webpage, I have updated the code to do that

Comment: <body> 

    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        const aeris = new AerisWeather('[ID]', '[SECRET]');

        const request = aeris.api()
            .endpoint('convective/outlook')
            .place('chicago,il')
            .format('json')
            .filter('all');
        request.get().then((result) => {
   console.log(result.details.risk.type);
     const outputDiv = document.getElementById("result"); 
     outputDiv.textContent += result.details.risk.type; 
        });
    });
    </script>
  
<div id="result"></div>

Comment: Still no luck with this type of body.

Comment: And what do you see in the console.log? https://www.techonthenet.com/js/open_console_log.php#:~:text=Steps%20to%20Open%20the%20Console%20Log%20in%20Google%20Chrome&text=By%20default%2C%20the%20Inspect%20will,written%20to%20the%20Console%20log.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'risk')

Comment: OK, this means that what you gave at the top as the JSON response, is not actually what you are receiving in `result`. Try with the small update I have added now, the extra line: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));`. This will help track down your error.

Comment: `        "product": "convective",
        "category": "cat",
        "day": 1,
        "range": {
          "minTimestamp": 1678046400,
          "maxTimestamp": 1678104000,
          "minDateTimeISO": "2023-03-05T14:00:00-06:00",
          "maxDateTimeISO": "2023-03-06T06:00:00-06:00"
        },
        "issuedTimestamp": 1678043820,
        "issuedDateTimeISO": "2023-03-05T13:17:00-06:00",
        "risk": {
          "type": "general",
          "name": "general thunderstorms risk",
          "code": 1

Comment: [link](https://dakotaradar.org/testrun.html)Test Run